# Error in blogdown serve_site() when updating a file

Tags: r, blogdown

I'm trying to set up my first website using blogdown in RStudio.

When I run serve_site() in RStudio I don't get any error:

```
> blogdown:::serve_site()
Building sites â€¦ 
                   | EN  
+------------------+----+
  Pages            | 45  
  Paginator pages  |  0  
  Non-page files   |  0  
  Static files     | 26  
  Processed images |  0  
  Aliases          |  0  
  Sitemaps         |  1  
  Cleaned          |  0  

Total in 120 ms
```

Although the symbols `â€` look weird.

However, when I edit the `config.toml` file and save the changes I get the following error:

> '---did you forget a '#'? at line 1>seImpl(path.expand(input), verbose, fromFile): Unidentified trailing character '

My set up is:

- Windows 10
- R Open 3.5
- RStudio 1.1.453
- hugo version: ‘0.41’
- hugo theme: mtn/cocoa-eh-hugo-theme

I tried to:
+ Install RStudio 1.2.720
+ Switch to R 3.5
+ update `blogdown` and `servr` to the last development version
+ create another blogdown project with the default theme

But nothing changed. I encounter the error only when changing the `config.toml`,
I tried with a `.md` file and I didn't get the error.

Comment: This happened to me a month or two ago using `hugo-xmin` theme.  I never figured out what the problem was, but at the time I worked around it by adding a "#" at the end of every line in `config.toml`.  I wasn't able to reproduce it on another computer (and in fact had to remove the "#" from the theme line to serve the site).  I'll try to remember to check next time I'm on my other computer to see if I can reproduce.

Comment: To follow-up, I can reproduce something similar. I get an error `Error in tomlparseImpl(path.expand(input), verbose, fromFile): '---did you forget a '#'? at line 1`. To make things a little odder, if I open the project, edit and save `config.toml`, and then serve the site I get that error.  If I then close the project and re-open it and serve the site everything is fine and I can continue to edit `config.toml` with no problems. I use `blogdown.generator.server = TRUE`.  I also tried updating various packages to current versions but didn't see anything change.

Comment: @aosmith Thank you. I tried using `options(blogdown.generator.server = TRUE)` and it works for me too.

Comment: Great!  Maybe put it as an answer for posterity?

Comment: Since I don't understand the error message, I just googled for it, and found this post: https://ellocke.github.io/post/r-troubleshooting-blogdown-hugo-for-windows-dummies/ (see Section 4). It seems the error was from the RcppTOML package, which is not strictly required by blogdown. Can you try to remove it and retry?

Comment: `remove.packages('RcppTOML')` worked, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue [was fixed](https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/commit/2112023c62bd33cb310a9df63c65029a5c7506b1) in **blogdown** 0.6.8 (currently on Github). You may

```
devtools::install_github('rstudio/blogdown')
```

If you prefer not using the development version of **blogdown**, you may just `remove.packages('RcppTOML')`.